# Eval -- Time Execution madly increases at each loop

Tags: php, performance, time, eval

I have this feed with 10,000 records and a loop to obtain all that products and then create a product array using those columns.

That map is created differently for each retailer, so product name can be the name of the product or it can be two columns of the feed. Below is an example.

The problem i am facing is that each loop after do eval, eval, eval... it starts increasing madly the time. Even when there are no functions at all.

Eval is creating references ? functions ? temp vars ? its there a way to reset all of that ?

**DEBUG TIME**

[2014-05-14 10:21:08][DEBUG] Converted 500 products in 0.48338389396667 Memory usage: 247750752 Read / Total: 500 / 108640

(...)

[2014-05-14 10:26:06][DEBUG] Converted 500 products in 6.9182150363922 Memory usage: 247751288 Read / Total: 50000 / 108640

(...)

[2014-05-14 10:28:03][DEBUG] Converted 500 products in 7.5416939258575 Memory usage: 247749704 Read / Total: 60000 / 108640

**EXAMPLE**

For the Merchant A i am getting the product name with this php function:

```
array_explode(",",str_replace(" ","",$NAME))[0];
```

So my mapping $v will have a index  "f" with the follow value:

```
array_explode(",",str_replace(" ","",$NAME))[0];
```

After i do the eval of that map

```
foreach($map as $k=>$v) {
    (...)
    $value = eval('return ' . $v["f"] . ";");
    (...)
}
```

This works just fine i get all my product array just fine, but this is increasing maddly the execution time of my script. If i take that away the script runs fines with a 0.4secs per 500 lines / products.

I need the eval as i am using php code to parse / style the feed.

Help ? :)

Comment: The code given is not enough to tell where the memory is allocated and where it might start to get slow. But what we can tell is, you could implement a cleaner solution without eval and with proper resource management.

Comment: Couldn't you be bothered to post the whole source code of the loop?!

Comment: Hello guys, i have edited. you dont need the whole loop. I already tested everything the loop is fine eval is not. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($map as $k=>$v) {
    (...)
    $value = eval('return ' . $v["f"] . ";");
    (...)
}
```

You cannot `return` from a foreach. You can but that would assume **1.** you are inside a function or method and **2.** only the first result would be returned, because after `return` it breaks the loop.

If I get this wrong, it doesnt make sense either, why don't you:

```
$value = $v["f"];
```

**Update:**

When, according to your comment, `$v["f"]` is a function, use `call_user_func` instead of `eval`:

```
$value = call_user_func($v["f"]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, eval is returning me the value of that field (with a function inside). I need to use return to that function, is not returning the for each, it has nothing to do with the foreach. It is there just as a friendly example

Comment: Its on the example above, it can be several php native functions or even static functions for my Helper class. for example: Helper::minPrice(array($rrp_price,$discount_price))

Answer (score 0):

Even ashamed to say that ... WAS MY FAULT!! No problem with it i was just running it with the -d xdebug.remote.autostart=1 and each eval was opening a xdebug thing.

Sorry :( thanks for your help guys!